# How to control segment info in gstreamer messages

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm writing a GStreamer application and I use GST_DEBUG_OBJECT() calls and alike all around my code. In some cases it produces output like this:

```
0:01:05.049031594  2014 UNDEFINED segment DEBUG ...
```

which would be good enough for my purposes. In other cases it decides to output the segment information like so:

```
0:01:57.617158397  2014 default segment start=4294967297, stop=0, last_stop=0, duration=13586288, rate=0.000000, applied_rate=0.000000, flags=0x00, time=0:00:00.000000000, accum=38:50:00.111740672 DEBUG ...
```

So, my question is where from it gets this 'default segment' information and how to control it?

So far what it prints is some bogus data and what I want is either eliminate this 'default segment' info completely or at least show some useful info from the actual segment. I went through documentation several times and even looked at the code, but couldn't find much myself.

I'm working with a custom build of GStreamer for an embedded device running Linux and I wonder if this is controlled via parameters of the build?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think this page will help you: http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+11%3A+Debugging+tools

Basically you'll define your own debug category with the following (all from the "Adding your own debug information" section):

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_STATIC (my_category);
#define GST_CAT_DEFAULT my_category
```

And then after you call gst_init(...) do this:

```
GST_DEBUG_CATEGORY_INIT (my_category, "my category name", 0, "Description of my category");
```

Once you do that you should see "my category name" instead of "UNDEFINED" or "default"...

This is for "standard" GStreamer, but it will hopefully also work for your custom build...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already know how to control the debugging output. My issue is with this segment info that GStreamer prints and I do not know how to control it. This segment info is just plain wrong on top of being irrelevant and it just pollutes the log.

Comment: -1. This has nothing at all to do with the question.